# How to add a HTML block dynamiclly into a page?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I need to add a block like this .

```
<td valign="bottom" width="25%">
            <a href="/images/00000.jpg">
            <img width="150" height="100" src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3114/2524849923_1c191ef42e.jpg" border="0" alt="Click" title="Click"></a>
        </td>
```

I am trying something like .But here the td element is not getting appended with the image element.

```
 var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = src;
        img.width = width;
        img.height = height;
        img.alt = alt;
        img.onclick=function () { alert(src); }; 
        td=td.appendChild(img);
        alert(td);
        document.body.appendChild(td);
```

Comment: Did you create the `td` element with `document.createElement("td")`? Also it's invalid to add a `td` to the body.. you should add it to a `tr` (which is inside a table).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work out (it creates exactly the structure mentioned):

```
td = document.createElement('td');
td.valign = 'bottom';
td.width = '25%';
a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = '/images/00000.jpg';
img = document.createElement('img');
img.width = '150';
img.height = '100';
img.border = '0';
img.alt = img.title = 'Click';
img.src = 'http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3114/2524849923_1c191ef42e.jpg';
a.appendChild(img);
td.appendChild(a);
document.body.appendChild(td);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TimWolla/PFVrG/

Answer (score 2):

```
td=td.appendChild(img);
```

At this line you're setting `td` to the result of the `appendChild` operation (which will be the image). Remove the `td=` part:

```
td.appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are are using jquery you could do something like this:

```
$('<td>....</td>').appendTo('#parent');
```

Where #parent is id of the parent html tag/container. There are also some ohter variants/methods if you don't want it to be appended as the last child element.

Comment: We use YUI , but its good to see how simple it can be with JQUERY .

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but the best answer is considerably easier than what's written above.

1. Create a temporary element:

   ```
    var el = document.createElement('img');
    el.id = 'tempID0';
   ```
2. Append said item to the wherever you want

   ```
    document.body.appendChild(el);
   ```
3. Modify the outerHTML of this element with a big block of HTML

   ```
    document.getElementById('tempID0').outerHTML = '<td>.....</td>';
   ```